# F# - Replace Float With Label Based On Percentile Comparison

Tags: arrays, dictionary, f#, percentile

I need to map the values in *tmp* to labels in *tmpRplcd* based on comparison with percentiles in *prcntls*, but the *Array.map2* line fails because the arrays are of different lengths.

```
module SOQN = 
   open System
   open MathNet.Numerics.Statistics
   let tmp = [| 13.0; 17.0; 23.0; 11.0; 11.0; 13.0; 31.0; 
                19.0; 47.0; 29.0; 29.0; 19.0; 43.0; 37.0 |]
   let tmpPrcntls = 
      tmp
      |> Array.sort
   let lbls = [| "p0"; "p1"; "p2"; "p3"; "p4";"p5" |]
   let prcntls = [| Statistics.Percentile(tmpPrcntls,0)   // 11.0
                    Statistics.Percentile(tmpPrcntls,20)  // 13.0
                    Statistics.Percentile(tmpPrcntls,40)  // 19.0
                    Statistics.Percentile(tmpPrcntls,60)  // 28.6
                    Statistics.Percentile(tmpPrcntls,80)  // 35.8
                    Statistics.Percentile(tmpPrcntls,100) // 47.0
                 |]
   let lkpTbl = Map(Array.zip prcntls lbls)
   let tmpRplcd:string[] = 
      tmp
      |> Array.map2 (fun x y -> if x <= y then lkpTbl.[y] else "") prcntls
   let main = 
      printfn ""
      printfn "Percentile Test"
      printfn ""
      printfn "tmpPrcntls: %A" tmpPrcntls
      printfn "prcntls:%A" prcntls
      printfn "tmpRplcd:%A" tmpRplcd
      0
   [<EntryPoint>]
   main
   |> ignore

 // Expected Result:
 // tmpRplcd = [| "p1"; "p2"; "p3"; "p0"; "p0"; "p1"; "p4"; 
 //               "p2"; "p5"; "p4"; "p4"; "p2"; "p5"; "p5" |]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your use of `map2` is wrong - the `map2` function zips the two arrays and then applies the given function to the zipped array.

Based on your question, my guess is that you actually want to do something else. For every input, you want to iterate over all percentiles and find the first percentile such that the value is greater (or smaller?) than the percentile. To do this, you need to replace `map2` with something like this:

```
let tmpRplcd:string[] = 
  tmp 
  |> Array.map (fun y -> 
    prcntls |> Array.tryPick (fun x ->
      if x <= y then Some(lkpTbl.[x]) else None))
  |> Array.map (fun v -> defaultArg v "")
```

I don't have the right version to try this, but I think this should do what you need (I'm just not sure if you need `x <= y` or the other way round!)

Comment: Excellent @TomasPetricek. _x >= y_ is the correct option. Thanks again for the clear explanation and the benefit of your expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Here follows an approach to what you'd intend to do with your F# program.

I came up with an implementation of the percentile calculation from http://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-calculate-percentiles-in-statistics/ , which is shown in the Statistics module below.

```
namespace FSharpBasics

module Statistics =
    let percentile p (array: float[]) =
        let threshold = (float p / 100.0) * float (array |> Array.length)
        let thresholdCeiling = int (System.Math.Ceiling threshold)
        let thresholdInteger = int (threshold)
        array
            |> Array.sort
            |> Array.skip (thresholdCeiling - 1)
            |> Array.truncate (if thresholdInteger = thresholdCeiling then 2 else 1)
            |> Array.average

module PercentileTest =
    open System

    let tmp = [| 13.0; 17.0; 23.0; 11.0; 11.0; 13.0; 31.0;
                 19.0; 47.0; 29.0; 29.0; 19.0; 43.0; 37.0 |]

    let lbls = 
        [| for n in 0..20..100 -> "p" + string (n / 20) |]

    let prcntls = 
        [| for n in 0..20..100 -> Statistics.percentile n tmp |]

    let tmpPrcntls = 
        tmp |> Array.sort

    let lkpTbl = 
        Array.zip prcntls lbls

    let tmpRplcd : string[] =
        tmp
        |> Array.map (fun x -> 
                lkpTbl 
                |> Array.filter (fun (prcntl, lbl) -> prcntl <= x)
                |> Array.last
                |> snd)

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        printfn ""
        printfn "Percentile Test"
        printfn ""
        printfn "tmp: %A" tmp
        printfn "tmpPrcntls: %A" tmpPrcntls
        printfn "prcntls: %A" prcntls
        printfn "tmpRplcd: %A" tmpRplcd
        System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        0 // return an integer exit code
(*---- output ----

Percentile Test

tmp: [|13.0; 17.0; 23.0; 11.0; 11.0; 13.0; 31.0; 19.0; 47.0; 29.0; 29.0; 19.0; 43.0;
  37.0|]
tmpPrcntls: [|11.0; 11.0; 13.0; 13.0; 17.0; 19.0; 19.0; 23.0; 29.0; 29.0; 31.0; 37.0; 43.0;
  47.0|]
prcntls: [|11.0; 13.0; 19.0; 29.0; 37.0; 47.0|]
tmpRplcd: [|"p1"; "p1"; "p2"; "p0"; "p0"; "p1"; "p3"; "p2"; "p5"; "p3"; "p3"; "p2"; "p4";
 "p4"|]
---- ----*)
```

Comment: @MarceloUchimura. Thank you for the detailed reply. Unfortunately, I am getting a mismatch between the expected output and the actual output generated by your program:

    // Expected Result:
    // tmpRplcd  = [| "p1"; "p2"; "p3"; "p0"; "p0"; "p1"; "p4"; 
                               "p2"; "p5"; "p4"; "p4"; "p2"; "p5"; "p5" |]
    // Actual Result:
    // tmpRplcd:   [| "p1"; "p1"; "p2"; "p0"; "p0"; "p1"; "p3"; 
                             "p2"; "p5"; "p3"; "p3"; "p2"; "p4"; "p4"|]

Comment: @matekus: probably the mismatch is due to the different statistical package being used. I am afraid the last value of 37.0 in _tmp_ cannot be in the p5 percentile because it is less than 47.0.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura, 37.0 should translate to "p5".

Comment: @matekus, I am afraid the only value in _tmp_ which belongs to p5 is 47.0, which is the greatest of all values in the list.